# Split files based on number of delimiters

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have malformed csv file that has different number of delimiters (delimiter is comma).
I need to split the source file into multiple files, based on number of delimiters.

```
$ cat ~/Desktop/sample_file.csv
1001,Pink,Panther,Seattle,WA,98001,favorite character
1002,Micky,Mouse,Bellevue,WA,98002
1003,Mini,Mouse,Bellevue,WA,98003
1004,Donald,Duck,Redmond,WA,98004,So funny
1005,Tom,Jerry,Lynwood,WA
1006,Woody,Woodpacker,Lynwood,WA
```

Need unix command to split it into multiple files based on number of delimiters.
For example, above sample file needs to be broken down into 3 files:

```
$ cat sample_file_6_delimiter.csv
1001,Pink,Panther,Seattle,WA,98001,favorite character
1004,Donald,Duck,Redmond,WA,98004,So funny

$ cat sample_file_5_delimiter.csv
1002,Micky,Mouse,Bellevue,WA,98002
1003,Mini,Mouse,Bellevue,WA,98003

$ cat sample_file_4_delimiter.csv
1005,Tom,Jerry,Lynwood,WA
1006,Woody,Woodpacker,Lynwood,WA
```

Comment: can commas appear as part of the data? if 'yes', please update the question with a couple sample rows

Comment: please update the question with the code you've tried and the (wrong) results generated by your code

Comment: Comma cannot be part of data.
It is just some record has incomplete data

Comment: I am not sure how to split file based on number of delimiters.
I played with AWK command to split the records but did not get anywhere

Comment: please update the question with some of your `awk` attempts and the (wrong) results generated by said code

Comment: ```awk -v RS='$' '{ outfile = "output_file_" NR; print > outfile}' sample_file.csv```

Ideas was to print each record into different file then work on logic to use count of filters to split it.
But script simply adding a line at end of existing file and printing to a new file.

Comment: please update the question with your coding attempt and results; not everyone is going to read through comments trying to piece together the entire picture; havind said that ... `NR` is number of records while what you want to work with is `NF` (number of fields) - see my answer for one idea

Comment: Regarding `-v RS='$'` - that sets the record separator to the literal character `$`. You have no `$`s in your input so the whole input file will be read as 1 record. Then `outfile = "output_file_" NR` is equivalent to `outfile = "output_file_1"` since `NR` will be `1`, and then `print` will print the whole input file, including it's terminating `\n`, followed by a new `\n` (the value of `ORS`. I recommend you get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn about awk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN  { FS = OFS = "," }                                     # set input/output field separator as ","; setting OFS is optional in this case since we always output the entire line (print $0)
FNR==1 { basename = FILENAME                                  # 1st record of file: make copy of input FILENAME
         sub(/.csv$/,"",basename)                             # strip ".csv" off end of filename
       }
       { print $0 > (basename "_" (NF-1) "_delimiter.csv") }  # "NF" == number of fields, "NF-1" == number of delimiters
' sample_file.csv
```

This generates:

```
$ head sample*delimiter.csv
==> sample_file_4_delimiter.csv <==
1005,Tom,Jerry,Lynwood,WA
1006,Woody,Woodpacker,Lynwood,WA

==> sample_file_5_delimiter.csv <==
1002,Micky,Mouse,Bellevue,WA,98002
1003,Mini,Mouse,Bellevue,WA,98003

==> sample_file_6_delimiter.csv <==
1001,Pink,Panther,Seattle,WA,98001,favorite character
1004,Donald,Duck,Redmond,WA,98004,So funny
```

Comment: Here is extension of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77829279/record-count-with-total-number-of-delimiters

@markp-fuso, please have a look